# Python Falcon Framework: optional URI parameters

Tags: python, falconframework

Is there a way to define *optional* path parameters in the Falcon web framework? Currently, I'm declaring separate routes for modifying the same resource.

```
app.add_route('/users/', users_api_post)
app.add_route('/users/{id}', users_api_put)
```

PS: There's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032066/flask-optional-url-parameters) on SO for Flask framework.

Comment: Can't you just create two routes that would be handled by the same controller?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that you are using different HTTP methods, so it seems simpler to use differente functions (on_put and on_post).

But if you are using the same HTTP method, this worked for me:

```
class EventsResource(object):
    def on_get(self, req, resp, app_id, timeanddate=None):
        if timeanddate:
            ...
        else:
            ...

app.add_route('/events/{app_id}', EventsResource())
app.add_route('/events/{app_id}/{timeanddate}', EventsResource())
```

Hope this helps...