# Optional parameters in flask add_url_rule

Tags: flask

I have a flask route `app.add_url_rule("/<string:name>",'welcome',DataProcessor.welcome)` what I want is to make the **name** parameter optional. How can I do it inside the `add_url_rule` method?

Answer (score 0):

`app.add_url_rule()` does exactly the same as the `@app.route()` decorator. Therefore, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032066/can-flask-have-optional-url-parameters) might help you out.

In short, it's not possible without setting default values to those parameters.

You can either use that approach, or use the `request.args`.