# Flask url redirect gives unexpected keyword argument exception

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to connect to different databased based on the URL parameter using flask

In defined the route as

```
@app.route('/data_service/file/<string:db>/', methods=['GET','DELETE','POST','PUT'])
def file():
```

However, flask complains that

```
TypeError: file() got an unexpected keyword argument 'db'
```

Imho this should work according to description, e.g. https://pythonprogramming.net/flask-url-converters-tutorial/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Flask have optional URL parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032066/can-flask-have-optional-url-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake

The parameter should have occurred in the function
in that case the code should have been

```
@app.route('/data_service/file/<string:db>/', methods=['GET','DELETE','POST','PUT'])
def file():
```

Comment: wasted now 2 hours and found the answer on my one once it was posted :-( still might be helpful for somebody else