# Two urls with difference of one optional parameter to map to same resource in flask restful

Tags: python, flask-restful

I have two endpoints:

- `/api/v1/users`
- `/api/v1/<resource>/users`

I have a class that handles for the latter like this

```
class ListUsers(Resource):
    def post(self,resource):
         // get the list of users under that resource

api.addResource(ListUsers,'/api/v1/<resource>/users')
```

If the `resource` is not specified, I want to list users from all resources. Is it possible to map both the urls to the same `class ListUsers` instead of writing another class for the first url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the the docs and source code for flask-restful, you can pass multiple urls to match to addResource.

like:

```
class ListUsers(Resource):
    def post(self, resource=None):
        // get the list of users under that resource

api.addResource(ListUsers, '/api/v1/<resource>/users', '/api/v1/users')
```

Another example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56250131/1788218

Useful docs: https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/flask-restful/latest/flask-restful.pdf

Comment: Nice simple solution :) !

Comment: I had the same problem last week, but in my case the urls had not the same prefix, they were completely different. This happened because I had to implement a new version fo the api together with the old one.

In the end I solved by copying and pasting the resource and registering the routes.