# Using an HTML form with Python Flask search a MongoDB collection

Tags: python, mongodb, forms, flask, search

I 'ld like  for a user to drop a random search in a search form for a book title  and find get results if the book is in the db. Below is part of the code block.
I 'm having some issues searching for a single document in my mongodb using a search field and search strings.  Below is the code. I'm trying to get the search result via the find_book route.
The code above with the /find_book/<book_id> returns errors.
Below is a part of my code in the app.py file and the search form.
I get the following errors.
***werkzeug.routing.BuildError
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'find_book'. Did you forget to specify values ['book_title']?
Traceback (most recent call last)***

```
  # create an instance of py_mongo with app as argument
mongo = PyMongo(app)


    @app.route('/')
    def home():
        return render_template('home.html')
    
    
    # define the various menu options
    @app.route('/get_books')
    def get_books():
        return render_template('books.html', books=mongo.db.books.find())
    
    
    # Add a book
    @app.route('/add_book')
    def add_book():
        return render_template('add_book.html',
                               faculties=mongo.db.faculties.find())
    
    
    # Add submit button for Books
    @app.route('/insert_book', methods=['POST'])
    def insert_book():
        book = mongo.db.books
        book.insert_one(request.form.to_dict())
        return redirect(url_for('get_books'))
    
    
    # wire the edit button
    @app.route('/edit_book/<book_id>')
    # description task, name, due date, is urgent fields will be
    # pre-populated based on the information returned in the task.
    def edit_book(book_id):
        a_book = mongo.db.books.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(book_id)})
        # category names will be prepolulated based on the collection
        # # of categories returned in the categories cursor
        all_faculties = mongo.db.faculties.find()
        return render_template('edit_book.html',
                               book=a_book, faculties=all_faculties)
    
    
    @app.route('/update_book/<book_id>', methods=['POST'])
    def update_book(book_id):
        # access the database collection
        book = mongo.db.books
        # call the update function, specify an id
        book.update({'_id': ObjectId(book_id)},
        {
            'faculty_name': request.form.get('faculty_name'),
            'subject_name': request.form.get('subject_name'),
            'book_title': request.form.get('book_title'),
            'book_author': request.form.get('book_author'),
            'book_description': request.form.get('task_description'),
            'lender_name': request.form.get('lender_name'),
            'due_date': request.form.get('due_date'),
            'is_available': request.form.get('is_urgent')
        })
        return redirect(url_for('get_books'))
    # specify the form fields to match the keys on the task collection
    
    
    # delete a book
    @app.route('/delete_book/<book_id>')
    def delete_book(book_id):
        mongo.db.books.remove({'_id': ObjectId(book_id)})
        return redirect(url_for('get_books'))
    
    
    # find a book by text search
    @app.route('/find_book/<book_title>', methods=['GET'])
    def find_book(book_title):
        book_title = mongo.db.books
        book_title.find_one(
        {
            'book_title': request.form.get('book_title'),
        })
        return render_template('find.html', book_title=book_title)
    
    
    # categories function
    @app.route('/get_faculties')
    def get_faculties():
        return render_template('faculties.html',
                               faculties=mongo.db.faculties.find())
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host=os.environ.get('IP'),
                port=int(os.environ.get('PORT')),
                debug=True)



<form action="{{ url_for('find_book') }}" method="GET">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Book Title" id="book_title" name="book_title" >
  <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search">Search</i></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `find_book` route is expecting an argument `book_title`

But you are not passing that in `{{ url_for('find_book') }}`

You could just change this route to `@app.route('/find_book')` and get the value from `request.form` or if you are using this route in another place of your application you could use the approach from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032066/can-flask-have-optional-url-parameters) and use this way:

```
@app.route('/find_book/', defaults={'book_title': None})
@app.route('/find_book/<book_title>')
def find_book(book_title):
    books = mongo.db.books
    if book_title is None:
        book_title = request.form.get('book_title')
    book = books.find_one({
        'book_title': book_title
    })
    return render_template('find.html', book=book)
```

I could not run this snippet of code now, so let me know if dont work.

Comment: I'm getting some results. But the find_one() only displays the first item in my collection which is not necessarily the result. An example of a search i just did. However this is not the book I searched for.

Subject Name
Book Title
Author
Description
Availability
Name of Lender
Due Date
 
Marine Sciense
Whales
Mark Jones sr
Secret song of whales
Jane Doe
28 July, 2020

Comment: This is the expected behavior from `find_one`. Try change to `find` to get a list of results or refine your search to use multiple parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You've really enabled me to carry on with this project.