# Redirect to the same page and display a message if user insert wrong data

Tags: python, flask

I am building a web chat application with chat rooms.
I have a page where users can open a new room, inside the page, there is a form.
I want to display a message to the user if he submits the form with a room that already exists.

---

For example:
Room 456 already exists and the user tried to open 456 room.
so I want to pop up a message that the room already exists.

---

The server side

```
    @app.route('/NewRoom')
def newRm():
    return render_template('NewRoom.html')

@app.route('/chat',methods=['GET','POST'])
def CreateRm():
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        username = request.form['username'].lower() 
        room = request.form['room'].lower()
        ExistRoom = DBManage.ExistRoom(room)
        error = "YOU ENTERED ROOM THAT ALREADY EXISTS"
        if not ExistRoom:
            limit = request.form['limit']
            if limit == '':
                limit = 'UNLIMITED'
            session['limit'] = limit 
            image = request.files['getFile']
            newImgs = open("static/images/" + username + ".jpg","wb")
            newImgs.write(image.read())
            newImgs.close()
            room = room[:5].strip()
            DBManage.newRoom(room,limit)
            DBManage.newPerson(username,room)
            #sDBManage.RoomUsers(room)
            #Store the data in session
            session['username'] = username
            session['room'] = room
            return render_template('chat.html', session = session)
        else:
            flash(error)
            return redirect(url_for('newRm',error=error))
```

Inside CreateRm function the else at the end didn't work for me well, it's refreshing the page but doesn't send the error message, not really know how to solve that.

---

Client side

```
{% if error %}
   <p class=error><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}
{% endif %}
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning a redirect to another route as well as trying to pass a variable to a template in that route. One way you could do this is by simply re-rendering the template, passing the variable, `error` to it at the same time. Try replacing:

```
return redirect(url_for('newRm',error=error))
```

with

```
return render_template('NewRoom.html', error=error)
```

---

Another option would be configuring your `newRm` route to accept [optional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14032066/15368978). This could look something like this:

```
@app.route('/NewRoom', defaults={'error':''})
@app.route('/Newroom/<error>')
def newRm():
    return render_template('NewRoom.html')
```

You then pass an error to this route exactly as you have been doing.

```
return redirect(url_for('newRm', error=error))
```

---

To completely solve your problem, you'll also have to add a `return` statement outside your `if(request.method=='POST'):` to catch any GET requests. It could be something like this:

```
return render_template('NewRoom.html')
```

Comment: It worked, but it shows me that error:
TypeError: The view function for 'CreateRm' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

Comment: Ok, this is probably happening when 'CreateRm' receives a GET request. This would result in the `if` statement not being run and the function ending without a return statement. (I'll edit my answer)