# How can i modify the url (Flask)

Tags: python, flask

I have this code:

```
def signup(fname, email, password):
    user={
        "name": fname,
        "email":email,
        "password":password
    }

@app.route('/', methods =["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":

       name = request.form.get("fname")
       email = request.form.get("email")
       password = request.form.get('password')

       signup(name, email, password)

       return redirect(url_for('user_blueprint.main', usr = name))
    return render_template('form.html')
```

Blueprint:

```
@user.route('/<usr>')
def main(usr):
    return f'Hello {usr}'
```

When I get to the page the url changes to ip/user/username, and if I change the 'username' of the url my html (which returns the name) also changes, can anyone tell me how to make my page no change? I dont mind if my url doesn't have to contain the username, but when i dont put it, flask gives me the error 'missing arguments'.

Comment: Might you be looking for [optional url parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14032066/15368978)? If not, then maybe you should edit your question to clarify your example situation. (like where is "ip/user/username" coming from?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're missing some part of the code, I'll assume some stuff, and then you can write a comment if I need to change stuff.

`@user` that you use in the second part of the code is `user_blueprint` and I assume you've registered it with the `user` prefix in the main application. So let me explain how you get URL `<IP>/user/<username>`.

When you call `url_for(user_blueprint.main, usr = name)` flasks looks for the blueprint and how it is registered, so it gets the prefix `user` from your configuration, then it replaces parameter `usr` in the only route you've registered, that is how you get `/user/<username>`.

So if you want to have unique URL then you need to remove `usr` from URL and try to pass `name` some other way (e.g. [session](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/quickstart/#sessions)). Here is example of code (just needed parts):

```py
from flask import session

@app.route('/', methods =["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
       ...
       session['usr'] = name
       return redirect(url_for('user_blueprint.main'))
    return render_template('form.html')

...
@user.route('/')
def main():
    return f'Hello {session['usr']}'
```

If you chose to use `session` here is a useful [link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.session) that you need to check before starting using session.