# I receive error message saying " raise ValueError(f"malformed url rule: {rule!r}") ValueError: malformed url rule: '/<King Solomon>'"

Tags: python, flask

In this code, if you navigate to '/King Solomon', the hello function should be called with name set to 'King Solomon', and it should return the string 'Hello, King Solomon!'. But It rather return this error

```
 raise ValueError(f"malformed url rule: {rule!r}")
ValueError: malformed url rule: '/<King Solomon>'
```

I tried this

```
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<King Solomon>')
def user(name):
    return f"Hello {name}!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and I was expecting and Output say "Hello King Solomon"

Answer (score 0):

I think the intent is that "King Solomon" is not known in advance and is provided by the user as part of the URL after the app is running.

Therefore, your code shouldn't include this string, but should provide `name` as a variable in the path, which the user can fill in when they type the URL into their browser or other request utility:

```py
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/<string:name>")
def user(name):
    return f"Hello {name}!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Usage:

```
$ curl http://localhost:5000/King%20Solomon
Hello King Solomon!
$ curl http://localhost:5000/whatever
Hello whatever!
```

You can also [provide a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032066/can-flask-have-optional-url-parameters) if you want:

```py
# ...

@app.route("/<string:name>")
@app.route("/", defaults={"name": "there"})
def user(name):
    ...

# ...
```

Usage:

```
$ curl http://localhost:5000/
Hello there!
```